# java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.airbnb.kafka.kafka08.StatsdMetricsReporter

Tags: apache-kafka, statsd

Working on setting up a monitoring system for a Kafka cluster using statsd. I'm using the statsd library [here](https://github.com/airbnb/kafka-statsd-metrics2). Currently my broker server won't start up.

I am positive my issue lies in this configuration line inside my `server.properties` file: `metric.reporters=com.airbnb.kafka.kafka08.StatsdMetricsReporter`.

When I comment that line out, the server starts up. Hell, I even get the statsd confirmation like this:

```
[2017-06-06 15:19:35,669] INFO Reporter is enabled and starting... (com.airbnb.metrics.StatsDReporter)
[2017-06-06 15:19:35,679] INFO Started Reporter with host=localhost, port=8125, polling_period_secs=10, prefix= (com.airbnb.metrics.StatsDReporter)
```

However, stats aren't reported (I believe) because this is also true: `metric.reporters = []`. Therefore, that line that's causing the issue must exist in the properties file, right?

When I try to start the server, it fails with this message:

```
[2017-06-06 15:21:34,712] FATAL [Kafka Server 0], Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.airbnb.kafka.kafka08.StatsdMetricsReporter
    at java.lang.Class.asSubclass(Class.java:3404)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.newInstance(Utils.java:356)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.getConfiguredInstances(AbstractConfig.java:243)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:198)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:39)
    at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:67)
    at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
[2017-06-06 15:21:34,713] INFO [Kafka Server 0], shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2017-06-06 15:21:34,714] INFO Terminate ZkClient event thread. (org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkEventThread)
[2017-06-06 15:21:34,718] INFO Session: 0x15c7ed717e30004 closed (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2017-06-06 15:21:34,720] INFO EventThread shut down for session: 0x15c7ed717e30004 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2017-06-06 15:21:34,720] INFO [Kafka Server 0], shut down completed (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2017-06-06 15:21:34,720] FATAL Fatal error during KafkaServerStartable startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable)
java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.airbnb.kafka.kafka08.StatsdMetricsReporter
    at java.lang.Class.asSubclass(Class.java:3404)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.newInstance(Utils.java:356)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.getConfiguredInstances(AbstractConfig.java:243)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:198)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:39)
    at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:67)
    at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
[2017-06-06 15:21:34,721] INFO [Kafka Server 0], shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
```

For the record, here is my config:

```
kafka:type=com.airbnb.kafka.kafka08.StatsdMetricsReporter
metric.reporters=com.airbnb.kafka.kafka08.StatsdMetricsReporter
kafka.metric.reporters=com.airbnb.kafka.kafka08.StatsdMetricsReporter
external.kafka.statsd.reporter.enabled=true
external.kafka.statsd.host=localhost
external.kafka.statsd.port=8125
external.kafka.statsd.metrics.prefix=
external.kafka.statsd.tag.enabled=true
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I had to use `kafka09` instead of `kafka08`.